# What does this block syntax do?

Tags: objective-c

I have this code which is part of a (pretty long) method signature:

```
[...]requestCreator:(NSURLSessionDataTask *(^)(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *, NSError *)))creator {
//
};
```

I don't quite get the fact that no variable names are there in parameters and what appears to be a type cast before.

Can someone break down this syntax and explain what's the behavior here?

Comment: It is a desperate cry for someone to declare, then use, a typedef to prevent the awfulness that is blocks taking blocks as parameters or return values.   (Which, btw, is nothing new;  C function pointers are equally as nasty.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the original method parameter declaration:

```
(NSURLSessionDataTask *(^)(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *, NSError *)))creator
```

The form of such a declaration is `(type)identifier`. So, the identifier is `creator` and the type is:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *(^)(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *, NSError *))
```

In a local variable declaration, that would look like this possibly more-familiar format, instead:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *(^creator)(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *, NSError *))
```

Let's rework that with some typedefs:

```
typedef void (^TaskErrorHandlerBlock)(NSURLSessionDataTask *, NSError *);
typedef NSURLSessionDataTask* (^TaskCreatorBlock)(TaskErrorHandlerBlock);
TaskCreatorBlock creator;
```

I've made up the names `TaskErrorHandlerBlock` and `TaskCreatorBlock` from my guess as to what they do. A `TaskCreatorBlock` is a block which returns an `NSURLSessionDataTask*` – it creates such a task object. It takes as input a `TaskErrorHandlerBlock`, which is presumably a block which is called if there's an error. It takes as parameters the task which encountered the error and the error itself.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a block that takes another block that gets a url session and error.

Comment: Probably the best type of block.  I can't think of any direct examples for it but there must be some good ones.